# Typeblock of left pages is shifted, but right pages are correct

Tags: lyx, memoir

I am writing a book using the `Memoir` class in `LyX`.
The typeblock of all left (even) pages is shifted, while the right (uneven) pages are correct. The effect is shown in the image, where the `\usepackage{showframe}` shows the layout. I am using the "Class Defaults" Page Margins.
The formatting statements in my LaTeX Preamble are

```
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{microtype}
\settypeblocksize{195mm}{122mm}{*}
\sloppybottom
\checkandfixthelayout
```

What am I doing wrong?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for comment, but this example is shown correctly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{microtype}
\settypeblocksize{195mm}{122mm}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{3cm}*1
\sloppybottom
\checkandfixthelayout
\begin{document}
\kant[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Thus you have something in your document you are not telling us about.

I added the `\setlrmarginsandblock` as it would not compile without it after that trimmed size

[image]

Comment: Well, the only thing I wasn't telling you about the fonts: \usepackage[euler-digits,euler-hat-accent]{eulervm} and \usepackage{concrete}, but is all.
Interestingly, your solutions works! Except that now the header is typeset in Italic CAPS.

Comment: @RomkeBontekoe that is the default in `in memoir`. Note that Lyx might be putting a lot more into the premable, and this it might be better export the doc to a proper LaTeX doc and have a look at the generated code.